# Send data from device based on connection speed

Tags: android, performance, connection, detection

In our Android App, we are sending data to the server in a background service. We would prefer this to be as frequently as possible.

Is there a way we can figure out the actual connection speed of the device's data link so that we make the httprequest based on this speed. We do not want to strain the slow link because it will impact our activity going on in the foreground.

Comment: Why don't you use sockets if you want to send the data so frequently?

Comment: Can sockets be used from android in communicating to web services. Any pointer on how this is done would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Node.js in the backend, you can go for Socket.io or you can use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).